# SAP crashes when using debugging mode of VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have a problem since last week, when I go through a VBA macro that launch SAP GUI commands with the debugger of visual basic (F8) it crashes my SAP session after 5 or 6 commands.

It's driving me crazy because it worked fine until last week..
I searched in google and I find several people having the same problem but nobody has an answer.
I also asked the IT support at my workplace and they told me that they haven't change anything..

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Here, I understand few words "crash", "vba", "debugger", "SAP GUI". It's impossible to help with so little information.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for my bad english. What I was saying is that : I have an excel macro that executes sap gui commands (ie:  session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press `) .
It works fine when I launch the macros but if I try to do a step by step with the vba debbugger it makes my sap session freeze then crash.
So there 2 things that I cant understand: first, why is it working when I dont stop it but it crashes when I go through step by step and second why does it not work now whereas it was working a week ago?

Comment: I mean, it's not your English, it's the information you provide. You still don't say anything more than the same words. What "crash" is it? Usually people tell to re-install software. What kind of log did you try to generate to see what's going on (SAP GUI trace). Did you install your SAP GUI again, did you install a more recent version, what are your versions, etc. Same for Office. Software are usually automatically upgraded nowadays, without noticing.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue sometimes.
Maybe you use too much object and don't set them to nothing quickly